# Load div based on [Slick] slider selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

The Slick slider loads fine and the initial div content below shows "asdf" as expected. When I click on any slider image now, the div below displays nothing. The 2nd "$('.group').hide();" is apparently executed correctly, just not the code after, so this should have nothing to do with the slider itself. I have tried various different approaches for the last 4 hours now and just cannot figure this out.

```
    <div class="carousel" id="selectMe">
            <div value="option1"><img src="image1.jpg"></div>
            <div value="option2"><img src="image2.jpg"></div>
            <div value="option3"><img src="image3.jpg"></div>
            <div value="option4"><img src="image4.jpg"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="option1" class="group">asdf</div>
    <div id="option2" class="group">kljh</div>
    <div id="option3" class="group">zxcv</div>
    <div id="option4" class="group">adfs</div>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.group').hide();
            $('#option1').show();
            $('#selectMe div').click(function () {
                $('.group').hide();
                var various = $(this).attr("value");
                console.log(various);
                $('#' + various).show();
            })
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.carousel').slick({
                dots: true,
                infinite: false,
                speed: 300,
                slidesToShow: 7,
                slidesToScroll: 7,
                responsive: [
                    {
                        breakpoint: 1024,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 6,
                            slidesToScroll: 6,
                            infinite: true,
                            dots: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 600,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 4,
                            slidesToScroll: 4
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 480,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 3,
                            slidesToScroll: 3
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: please give me a link of the lib which is used in your code

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#getting-started

Comment: CSS

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>

JS

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

Comment: Can you not add the group elements inside each slick slide? as the slick slides accept HTML as well as images, that way you would not need to do extra JS to sync the two elements.

Comment: I am not sure if I am following you. I am trying to load content below the whole slider, based on the slider selection, how would your suggestion avoid JS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.group').hide();
        $('#option1').show();
        $('#selectMe div').click(function (ev) {

            console.log($(ev.currentTarget).attr("value") )
            if (!$(ev.currentTarget).attr("value")) {
                return
            }
            $('.group').hide();
            var various = $(this).attr("value");

            console.log(various);
            $('#' + various).show();
        })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked! I am still learning, will have to study your code a bit now ;)

Comment: ooooh, I found this lib will change your code structure. you can inspect your HTML code and to see what happens